# Error when estimating contract deployment fee using web3.eth.estimateGas

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

When I run the code line below:

```
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({from:myAddress, data: bytecode})
```

got and error:

```
> Error: Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction"}
```

How fix it? many thanks.

Comment: are you missing await ? let gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({from:myAddress, data: bytecode})

Comment: It's because your transaction is going to fail. Did you try to deploy in the remix?

Comment: I can deploy the contract with constant gas, I want to use the estimated gas, but when I uncomment the two lines. there is always an error as above said. The code used: const main = async () => {
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(myAddress, "123456", 600);
    //let gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({from:myAddress, data: bytecode});
    //console.log(gasEstimate);
    await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
         .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['TestToken', 'Token', 18, '1000000000000000000000']})
        .send({ from:myAddress,
            gas: 6000000
        });
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you,

```js
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

const estimateGas = await contract.deploy({
  data: bytecode
}).estimateGas();

contract.deploy({
  data: bytecode,
  arguments: ['TestToken', 'Token', 18, '1000000000000000000000']
})
.send({
  from: yourAddress,
  gas: estimateGas,
})
.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
.on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
  console.log(transactionHash)
});
```

Comment: It works well.Thanks for your timely help! One comment is that under the line 4 "data: bytecode, ", "arguments: ['TestToken', 'Token', 18, '1000000000000000000000']" should be added, otherwise it can not pass the grammar check.

Comment: A question about contract deployment, I notice remix's generated code to deploy contract is as below:var TestToken = TestTokenContract.new(
   _name,
   _symbol,
   _decimals,
   _totalSupply,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
     data: '0xAAAAA...',
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
what's the difference between it and method you mentioned above?